# Using dependent CocoaPod in private CocoaPod

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods

I'm trying to use other CocoaPod in my own Pod, specifically this one. It adds case support to string extending `String` class:

https://github.com/Rabursky/StringCase

I've added

```
s.dependency 'StringCase'
```

to the podspec and run

```
pod install
```

The pod was successfully installed and I can also see it under Pods in Xcode and it was automatically linked to the target.

However, when I'm trying to use this extension in "Development Pod" it is not working. Getting error

> Value of type 'String' has no member 'cased'.

Answer (score 1):

You've listed this dependency in your podspec, which will be read by other machines to see what settings and dependencies are needed.

However this won't be used/read when you are building your own pod in Xcode. You need to create a `podfile` for your Xcode project, and include that string pod in it so that your local environment also has the necessary dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

- Try to clear build folder in your Xcode (cmd + shift + K).
- If it didn't work try to delete your derivedData folder of this project:
  open Xcode preferences(command + ,) > Locations > Derived Data then click on the little arrow to go to the derived data folder.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was, I was missing import statement at the top of the file.